# Error inserting word into Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list

So I have my Linked List struct here

```
struct ListNode
{
    string item;
    ListNode *next;
};

ListNode *head;
ListNode *cur;
ListNode *prev;
ListNode *search();
```

And my method to add nodes into Linked List

```
inline void List::guessedWords( string guess )
{
cur = head;

while ( cur != NULL )
{
    ListNode *newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->item = guess;

    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        newNode->next = NULL;
        head = newNode;
    }

    else
    {
        prev = search();
        newNode->next = cur;
        prev->next = newNode;
    }

    cur = newNode;
}
}
```

Anyone can point to my what's my mistakes? I couldn't get to add the first node.
Search function is to traverse to the end of node. What I'm trying to do is to keep on adding words into the back of he node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop looks a bit strange, you don't need a loop to insert a single element given the `search()` function (which an be replaced with a pointer called `tail`) Also,

```
cur = head;
while ( cur != NULL )
{   /* .... */
    if ( head == NULL )
```

the above `head == NULL` can never evaluate to true because the while condition already filters out that possibility.

```
head = tail = NULL;
inline void List::guessedWords( string guess )
{

    ListNode *newNode = new ListNode;
    newNode->item = guess;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if ( head == NULL )
    {
        head = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newNode;
    }

}
```

Comment: If head==NULL is wrong, how will I check whether my head is NULL or not to insert the first element.

Comment: You do check it in the while condition. Do you agree that `head == NULL` can not evaluate to true?

Comment: I've omit the while loop. Yea, sounds not right with the while loop. Don't know what's my brain is thinking. Problem still the same, I couldn't get to insert the first node. Well, if head == NULL cannot be true, what will my condition be? Sorry for stupid question, I'm new to Linked List and got short time to learn.

Comment: updated the answer, but also you may have some trouble with the `search` function. I don't know where you want to insert the node but if you just want to insert at the end keep track of the tail node and assign it's `next` to the new node.

Comment: Yea, just inserting my guess words into the end. I don't quite understand what you mean by "assign next to new node". What you meant is by next = newNode?

Comment: Thanks for pointing my mistakes, will try on my own first. If I still cant get it, I'll just have to follow your way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are missing, 
 tail = tail->next; just after 
tail->next = newNode;

it would ensure that tail is updated to the last node.